# Copy shadow with a fit node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use the copy shadow over a fit node, which wraps other fit node:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,shadows,positioning,backgrounds,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
    \tikzstyle{node1} = [rectangle, rounded corners, align=center, minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=0.3cm, text centered, draw=black!20, fill=black!10, font=\small]    
    \tikzstyle{node2} = [rectangle, rounded corners, align=center, minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=0.3cm, text centered, draw=black!20, fill=black!10, font=\small]
    \tikzstyle{container1} = [inner sep=7pt, draw=black!20, rounded corners, line width=0.6mm]
    \tikzstyle{bignode1} = [inner sep=3pt, fill=black!50, draw=black!20, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{bignode2} = [inner sep=3pt, fill=black!60, draw=black!20, rounded corners]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, auto, thick, black!80] 
    \tikzset{multiple/.style = {double copy shadow={shadow xshift=1ex,shadow yshift=-1.5ex,draw=black!30},fill=white,draw=black,thick,minimum height = 1cm,minimum width=2cm}}  

    \node[node1, label={[name=id1Lbl]Label 1}] (id1) {Text 101};
    \node[node1, right=0.4cm of id1] (id2) {Text 101};  
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  
      \node[bignode1] [fit={(id1Lbl) (id1) (id2)}] (idbig1) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \node[node2, label={[name=id2Lbl]Label 2}, below right=1.5cm and -0.6cm of id1] (id3) {Text 102};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  
      \node[bignode2] [fit={(id2Lbl) (id3)}] (idbig2) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \draw[arrow] (id1.south) -- (idbig2.north);
    \draw[arrow] (id2.south) -- (idbig2.north);

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      %\node[container1] [fit={(idbig1) (idbig2)}, draw=black!20, rounded corners, label={[name=cont1Lbl]Container1}] (cont1) {};  
      \node[multiple] [fit={(idbig1) (idbig2)}, draw=black!20, rounded corners, label={[name=cont1Lbl]Container1}] (cont1) {};  
    \end{pgfonlayer}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However I'd like to keep the background color for **idbig1** and **idbig2**, like when I use:

```
\node[container1] [fit={(idbig1) (idbig2)}, draw=black!20, rounded corners, label={[name=cont1Lbl]Container1}] (cont1) {};
```

[image]

In short, I'd like to keep the background for those nodes and show the doble copy shadow. Would that be possible with the fit node wrapping other fit node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

[image]

for above image you need todefine more bacground layer. Also is sensible to define common style for al other styles and merge to style "container1" style for `copy shadow`. :

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, backgrounds, calc, fit, 
                positioning, shapes, shadows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}% <-- added
\pgfdeclarelayer{back background}% <-- added
   \pgfsetlayers{back background,% <-- added
                 background,%
                 main}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 15mm and 4mm,% <-- added
% tikzstyle is depreciated, instead them the styles can be 
% defined as option of tikzpicture
 arrow/.style = {draw=black!80, thick, -stealth', shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt},
  base/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black!20, fill=black!10,
                 font=\small, align=center},
 node1/.style = {base, minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=0.3cm},
  bignode1/.style = {base, fill=black!40},
  bignode2/.style = {base, fill=black!60},
container1/.style = {base, line width=0.6mm, fill=white,
                     double copy shadow={shadow xshift=1ex, shadow yshift=-1.5ex}}
                        ]
\node[node1, label={[name=id1Lbl]Label 1}]  (id1) {Text 101};
\node[node1, right=of id1]                  (id2) {Text 101};
%
\node[node1, label={[name=id2Lbl]Label 2},
      below=of $(id1)!0.5!(id2)$]           (id3) {Text 102};
%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[bignode1] [fit=(id1Lbl) (id1) (id2)]  (idbig1) {};
\node[bignode2] [fit=(id2Lbl) (id3)]        (idbig2) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
%
\draw[arrow]    (id1.south) -- (idbig2.north);
\draw[arrow]    (id2.south) -- (idbig2.north);
%
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{back background}
\node[container1, fit=(idbig1) (idbig2),
      label=Container1]     {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```